# How do I handle arrays that are returned in json format?

Tags: json, django, angular, http

I am trying to get items in an array that is in a json response. When I try to log response in my console, I can see the array and it's items, but when I try to access an item in the array, I get "[object Object]" instead.

```
JSON response:

{ email: "test@test.com"
  groups: [{
      id: '1'
      name: 'admin' 
  }]
 id: 1
 is_active: true
 last_login: "2019-02-12T23:22:50.440290Z"
 username: "test" }
```

I've already tried:

```
user.groups.name
user.groups(['name'])
user.groups[2]
```

//this is the method that requests the response

```
getUserData(){
  this.userService.getUserDetails().subscribe(
  response => {
     this.users = response;
     console.log(response);
   },
   error => console.log('Error', error)
 );
}
```

//this is how I am calling the response in my html component file

```
  <div *ngFor="let user of users">

    {{ user.username }}
    {{ user.groups }}


  </div>
```

I need to access the "name" attribute and print out 'admin' in my div tags.

Comment: try to print your data in html first using `{{users | json}}`

Comment: That's not JSON. Do you mean to say that's the dict you are passing to `JsonResponse`? Then have you tried `user.groups[0].name`?

Comment: if I do {{ user.groups | json}} I get   [ { "id": 1, "name": "Admin" } ]   I need just "Admin"

Comment: user.groups[0].name works! Thank you! Now the only thing is that it crashes when a user doesn't have a group. I think I should handle it by assigning a default group when a new user is created.

Comment: let name=user.group?user.group.length?user.group[0].name:null:null; in .html you can use the safe operator {{user?.group[0]?.name}} https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Comment: @Eliseo `let name = user.group && user.group[0] && user.group[0].name` is somewhat shorter.